# SCP EC2 instance to local

Tags: amazon-ec2, scp

I have searched through the site looking for a solution, but I'm yet to be successful. I am attempting to get a file from my AWS ec2 instance onto my local desktop for viewing purposes. I have seen several times that the correct way is to use this command from the local computer:

```
scp -i ec2key.pem username@ec2ip:/path/to/file .
```

and I have been careful about all syntax especially including the "." so it saves to the current directory. However when I run this command I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname [ec2 ip]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using the ip, try with the hostname, or viceversa

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the public ip, and not the private ip of the instance?

Comment: My Instance was not assigned a public ip, however I use the private ip when sending files in the other direction and that works fine. Additionally, it is returning the private ip as the hostname. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Removed "ip-" in front of my private ip address. i.e

```
@ip-000-00-000-00 ...
```

Where it should be

```
@000-00-000-00
```